# cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to destroy an instance of jQuery UI's draggable, but I'm receiving a 'cannot call method' error.

**My code**

```
$('table.paper tr').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $('body').on('click', '[data-action="edit-ingredients"]', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('table.paper').draggable('destroy');
        });
    },
    start: function(event, ui) {
        c.tr = this;
        c.helper = ui.helper
        $(this).hide();
    },
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var collides = $('table.paper').overlaps($(c.helper));
        if (collides.hits.length) {
            $(c.helper).removeClass('delete');
        } else {
            $(c.helper).addClass('delete');
        }
    }
});
```

**The error**
`Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
Line 2`

In 'logic speak', this error is telling me my flow of code isn't correct as jQuery UI's draggable isn't initiated when I attempt to destroy it - however, as you can see I am creating the event listener within the draggable's 'create' event.

Comment: you are instantiating a draggable with selector `$('table.paper tr')` then destroying a draggable with a different selector `$('table.paper')` which i assume is not a draggable element

Comment: @pumpkinzzz God dammit, it's Monday! Thanks for pointing that out. Such a waste of content on SO now. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: ahaha np mate. answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are instantiating a draggable with selector `$('table.paper tr')` then destroying a draggable with a different selector `$('table.paper')` which i assume is not a draggable element.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, one of the best solutions to know if an element is draggable or not is to check if there is a class named `.ui-draggable`.